# A question on geometry

Tags: geometry, circles

Two circles $c_1$ and $c_2$ intersect each other at points $A$ and $B$. Their external common tangent closer to $B$ touches $c_1$ at $P$ and $c_2$ at $Q$. Let point $C$ be the reflection of $B$ in the line $PQ$. Prove that angle $CAP$ = angle $BAQ$.

Comment: This is actually a neat, fun problem, it is possibly slightly beyond being a regular homework assignment and it should not be put on hold (no additional context is necessary). Students could learn from asking about the solutions of slightly more interesting problems. Seeing how different tools from synthetic Euclidean geometry come together could help them improve their problem solving skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume circle $c_1$ has smaller radius than $c_2.$ Extend the two common tangents to $c_1$ and $c_2$ until they intersect at a common point $O$ and draw the circle $c_O$ with center $O$ passing thorough point $A$. Then $c_O$ also passes through $B$ and $C$. consequently, $$\angle \, BAC = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, BOC = \angle \, BOP$$ Let $\angle \, BAP = \alpha$ and $\angle \, BAQ = \beta$. Then $\angle \, BPQ = \angle \, BAP = \alpha$ and $\angle \, BQP = \angle \, BAQ = \beta$ because these are angles associated to the common tangent $PQ$ to $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Let $OB$ intersect $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $B_1$ and $B_2$, respectively, as second points of intersection. If you perform a homothety with center $O$ mapping $c_1$ to $c_2$ then $B_1$ is mapped to $B$ and $B$ is mapped to $B_2$, while $P$ is mapped to $Q$ (tangent points). Therefore 
$$\angle \, OBP = \angle \, B_1BP = \angle \, BB_2Q = \angle \, BQP = \beta$$ 
Form triangle $OBP$
$$\angle \, BOP = \angle \, BPQ - \angle \, OBP = \alpha - \beta$$
Then
$$\angle \, BAC = \angle \, BOP = \alpha - \beta$$
Consequently, $$\angle \, CAP = \angle \, BAP - \angle \, BAC = \alpha - (\alpha - \beta) = \beta = \angle \, BAQ$$

[image]

Alternatively, if you are a fan of inversions, you can perform inversion with respect to $c_O$. Then circle $c_1$ is mapped to circle $c_2$ (and vice versa) and point $P$ is mapped to $Q$. Therefore if you wish $OP \cdot OQ = OB^2$ which leads to $\angle \, OBP = \angle \, BQP = \beta$ or if you prefer the circle $c^*$ passing through $P, B, Q$ is mapped to itself, so it is orthogonal to $c_O$ which means that $OB$ is tangent to circle $c^*$ at point $B$ and again  $\angle \, OBP = \angle \, BQP = \beta$.

Comment: Wow! A real tour de force! Fantastic!

Comment: Thank you! And thank you very much for the picture!